# How can I clone a form and change the id of its inputs for 2,3 times?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clone

I've been trying to clone an element of a form and change the id of its children.
The thing I've not achieved is to clone the element for 3 or 4 times and the inputs of each clone need to have different id's, so I can work with the form.
It would be great if you could help me with some code, because I'm just beginning with JQUERY and Javascript!
Thanks a lot in advance!

HTML

```
          <div class="input-form fcf-form-group">

            <div class="form only">
              <h3 class="fcf-h3">Room</h3>
              <div class="form-section">

                <div class="title-group">
                  <label for="zimmer" class="fcf-label">Room</label>
                  <select name="zimmer" id="zimmer" required>
                    <option value="double">Double</option>
                    <option value="single">Single</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form neighbour">

              <div class="title-group small">
                <label for="erwachsene" class="fcf-label">Adults</label>
                <input type="number" id="erwachsene" name="erwachsene" min="1" max="5">
              </div>

              <div class="title-group small">
                <label for="kinder" class="fcf-label">Children</label>
                <input type="number" id="kinder" name="kinder" min="1" max="5">
              </div>

              <div class="title-group small">
                <label for="alter" class="fcf-label">Age of the Child</label>
                <select name="alter" id="alter" required>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="fcf-form-group">
            <button class="clone-button">zimmer</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see any JavaScript / jQuery code in your post. What have you tried? You might consider making a Template versus cloning an existing element.

Comment: Simple, change ALL `id` for a class... And update the functions that were related to an `id`. They will need to look for the class inside a specific `form`.  -- Whatever markup that is planned to be cloned should not include any `id`.

Comment: In this case using IDs is probably not the best option as it adds unneeded complexity to your process. There are a myriad of ways to refer to specific elements without the need of IDs.

Comment: @louysPatriceBessette okay great thank you! But do you also know how I need to change this part of my php if I change the id to a class?:                                                                           $zimmer = $_POST['zimmer'];
$erwachsene = $_POST['erwachsene'];
$kinder = $_POST['kinder'];
$alter = $_POST['alter'];

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How can I clone a form and change the id of its children more than just once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893536/how-can-i-clone-a-form-and-change-the-id-of-its-children-more-than-just-once). Why are you asking the question again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I clone a form and change the id of its children more than just once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893536/how-can-i-clone-a-form-and-change-the-id-of-its-children-more-than-just-once)

Comment: @terrymorse yes sorry! I asked the same question again because the answers I got the last time did not work for me! I'm just a beginner so sorry! Thanks a lot for your answer anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button.clone-button").click(function() {
    var clForm = $(".input-form:eq(0)").clone();
    var c = $(".input-form").length;
    $(".fcf-h3", clForm).html("Room " + c);
    var cur, tar;
    $("label, input, select", clForm).each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).is("label")) {
        cur = $(el).attr("for");
        if (cur.indexOf("-") > -1) {
          tar = cur.substr(0, cur.length - 2) + "-" + c;
        } else {
          tar = cur + "-" + c;
        }
        $(el).attr("for", tar);
      } else {
        cur = $(el).attr("id");
        if (cur.indexOf("-") > -1) {
          tar = cur.substr(0, cur.length - 2) + "-" + c;
        } else {
          tar = cur + "-" + c;
        }
        $(el).attr("id", tar);
      }
    });
    $(this).parent().before(clForm);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-form fcf-form-group">
  <div class="form only">
    <h3 class="fcf-h3">Room</h3>
    <div class="form-section">
      <div class="title-group">
        <label for="zimmer" class="fcf-label">Room</label>
        <select name="zimmer" id="zimmer" required>
          <option value="double">Double</option>
          <option value="single">Single</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form neighbour">
    <div class="title-group small">
      <label for="erwachsene" class="fcf-label">Adults</label>
      <input type="number" id="erwachsene" name="erwachsene" min="1" max="5">
    </div>
    <div class="title-group small">
      <label for="kinder" class="fcf-label">Children</label>
      <input type="number" id="kinder" name="kinder" min="1" max="5">
    </div>
    <div class="title-group small">
      <label for="alter" class="fcf-label">Age of the Child</label>
      <select name="alter" id="alter" required>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fcf-form-group">
  <button class="clone-button">zimmer</button>
</div>
```

If you are changing the `id` attribute you may also want to consider changing the `for`  on your `label` elements. Also since you have `label`, `input`, and `select` elements, you have to adjust a number of them.

Once cloned, you can then find the various elements and adjust their respective attributes.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

**Update**

For the PHP receiving this data, you'll want to send an Array of data, by setting the `name` attribute proper. You can leave the `id` attributes to the same script for HTML.

Reference:

```
<select name="zimmer[]" id="zimmer" required>
```

When this data arrives in PHP, you call it the same way, but it will be an Array of data that was entered into each form field.

```
echo $_POST['zimmer'][0];
```

See More: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: @friedl I updated it a bit. If it helps, I hope you will upvote it. If it answers your question, I hope you will Mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: one question: this section I mentioned above is just one section of a bigger form. When I click on the button to clone the element, every required field of the whole form which is not filled becomes red. Do you know how I can solve that?

Comment: @friedl there is not really a way to solve that. When the new elements are added, they have no content. So this triggers the browser to highlight them, indicating to the User they are required and must be filled in. If you add `true` to your `.clone()` it will copy the values; but then the User has to reset each anyway. You could make your own check and execute it on `submit` instead of using `required` attribute.

Comment: Alright! Thanks a lot for your answer! I've been working on this so long! Finally it worked! Thanks!